# How to disable grouping on one column in react-table V7

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

I use the `react-table` example at this [official codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/grouping).

The code for columns is like this:

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [{
            Header: 'Name',
            columns: [{
                    Header: 'First Name',
                    accessor: 'firstName',
                    // Use a two-stage aggregator here to first
                    // count the total rows being aggregated,
                    // then sum any of those counts if they are
                    // aggregated further
                    aggregate: ['sum', 'count'],
                    Aggregated: ({
                        cell: {
                            value
                        }
                    }) => `${value} Names`,
                },
                {
                    Header: 'Last Name',
                    accessor: 'lastName',
                    // Use another two-stage aggregator here to
                    // first count the UNIQUE values from the rows
                    // being aggregated, then sum those counts if
                    // they are aggregated further
                    aggregate: ['sum', 'uniqueCount'],
                    Aggregated: ({
                        cell: {
                            value
                        }
                    }) => `${value} Unique Names`,
                },
            ],
        },
        ...
    ],
    []
)
```

How could one disable grouping for i.e. `Last Name` column? I tried:

```
{
    Header: 'Last Name',
    accessor: 'lastName',
    disableGrouping: true, // This line
},
```

But `disableGrouping` does not work.

Best Regards

Answer (score 4):

Return all headings as a single array.

```
// Before
    const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [{
        Header: "Name",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "First Name",
            accessor: "firstName",
          },
          {
            Header: "Last Name",
            accessor: "lastName",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        Header: "Info",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "Age",
            accessor: "age",
          },
        ],
      }],
    []
  );



// After
    const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [{
            Header: "First Name",
            accessor: "firstName",
          },
          {
            Header: "Last Name",
            accessor: "lastName",
          },
          {
            Header: "Age",
            accessor: "age",
          }],
    []
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be the one you are looking for:

```
canGroupBy: Boolean
```

I had a look through the docs here [Column Props](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/docs/api/useGroupBy.md#column-properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can use option `disableGroupBy: true`

```
{
    Header: 'Last Name',
    accessor: 'lastName',
    disableGroupBy: true, // Updated to
}
```

Reference: https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useGroupBy#column-options

Answer (score 0):

Use `disableGroupBy` on the column (an object in your memoized `columns` array for example).

https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useGroupBy#column-properties